# ReactDOMServer - how to ignore trans-pile some values with renderToString method

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-dom

sometime, i want ignore trans-pile in renderToString.

i'm using React as template engine to generate base of template (html, header, body). i need to inject a value (a json object as string,converted with JSON.stringify) to can access to it as global variable on the browser.

this is my Template component:

```
export default function (props) {
    return (
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charSet="utf-8"/>
            </head>
            <body className="rtl">
                <div id="app-root"></div>
                <script>
                    myValue = {JSON.stringify(props.obj)}
                </script>
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

this is render and pass value place:

```
let template = <Template obj={obj}/>;

template = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(template);

template = '<!DOCTYPE html>' + template;

res.status(status).send(template);
```

after running this, 'myValue' is undefined because renderToString insert insert as HTML comment and also change structure of data (convert characters) like this:

```
<script>
myValue = <!-- -->{&quot;a&quot;:&quot;a&quot;,&quot;b&quot;:&quot;b&quot;}
</script>
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html.
Like this:

```
<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={JSON.stringify(props.obj)} />
```

Comment: dont work. Invariant Violation: `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML` must be in the form `{__html: ...}`

Comment: i edit your answer to truest solution. dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 'myValue =' + JSON.stringify(props.obj)}}